# Reason for adding 1 to word index for sequence modeling

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I notice in many of the tutorials `1` is added to the `word_index`. For example considering a sample code snippet inspired from `Tensorflow's` tutorial for `NMT` https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention :

```
import tensorflow as tf
sample_input = ["sample sentence 1", "sample sentence 2"]
lang_tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer(filters='')
lang_tokenizer.fit_on_texts(sample_input)
vocab_inp_size = len(lang_tokenizer.word_index)+1
```

I dont understand the reason for adding `1` to the `word_index dictionary`. Wont adding a `random 1` affect the prediction. Any suggestions will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation: layers.Embedding](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/): the **largest integer** in the **input** should be smaller than the **vocabulary size / input_dim**.

> **input_dim**: Integer. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. **maximum integer index + 1**.

That's why

```
vocab_inp_size = len(inp_lang.word_index)  + 1
vocab_tar_size = len(targ_lang.word_index) + 1
```

---

For example, consider the following cases,

```
inp = np.array([
  [1, 0, 2, 0],
  [1, 1, 5, 0],
  [1, 1, 3, 0]
])
print(inp.shape, inp.max())

'''
The largest integer (i.e. word index) in the input  
should be no larger than vocabulary size or input_dim in the Embedding layer. 
'''

x = Input(shape=(4,))
e = Embedding(input_dim = inp.max() + 1 , output_dim = 5, mask_zero=False)(x)

m = Model(inputs=x, outputs=e)
m.predict(inp).shape
(3, 4) 5
(3, 4, 5)
```

The `input_dim` of the `Embedding` layer should be greater than `inp. max()`, the otherwise error will occur. Additionally, the `mask_zero` is the default `False`, but if it sets `True` then as a consequence, index `0` can't be used in the vocabulary. According to the [doc](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/):

> **mask_zero**: Boolean, whether or not the input value 0 is a special
> "padding" value that should be masked out. This is useful when using
> recurrent layers which may take variable length input. If this is
> True, then all subsequent layers in the model need to support masking
> or an exception will be raised. If mask_zero is set to True, as a
> consequence, index 0 cannot be used in the vocabulary (input_dim
> should equal **size of vocabulary + 1**).

So, if we set `mask_zero` to `True` in the above examples, then the `input_dim` of the `Embedding` layer would be

```
Embedding(input_dim = inp.max() + 2 , output_dim = 5, mask_zero=True)
```